# How to run objects_counting_dmap correctly after training with default data?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

Using [objects_counting_dmap](https://github.com/NeuroSYS-pl/objects_counting_dmap/tree/master) (which is not my repo) I collected data with `python3 get_data.py --dataset cell`, trained the model with `python3 train.py -d cell -n UNet`, then attempted to run `python3 infer.py -n UNet -c cell_UNet.pth -i media01.png --visualize` and I get different errors depending on what I try.

PNG (`python3 infer.py -n UNet -c cell_UNet.pth -i media01.png --visualize`):

```
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1, 4, 164, 174] to have 3 channels, but got 4 channels instead
```

JPG (`python3 infer.py -n UNet -c cell_UNet.pth -i media01.jpg --visualize`): RuntimeError:

```
Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1. Expected size 40 but got size 41 for tensor number 1 in the list.
```

I tried fixing the PNG issue by changing line 70 in infer.py from `input_channels = 3` to `input_channels = 4`. This gave me another error

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for DataParallel:
    size mismatch for module.block1.0.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([64, 3, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([64, 4, 3, 3]).
```